# What does SQL server do when it is requested to order by 10*rand() expression?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This works:

```
select *
from <talbe_name>
order by <column_number>
```

This doesn't:

```
select *
from <table_name>
order by <column_number>+1
```

> Msg 408, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 A constant expression was
>   encountered in the ORDER BY list, position 1.

And this works:

```
select *
from <table_name>
order by 100*rand()+60;
```

but results of the select seem to be stable.
I'm curios how SQL Server interprets this order by query?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/955/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-a-random-ordering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have to have a constant number in the sort otherwise it will sort on value of the expression and not the column with the columnnumber of the value of the expression.

```
100*rand()+60;
```

That will give you a same value on all rows (try adding it to your select statment and you will se).

```
order by 1 desc
```

will sort on column one, because its a constant.

Comment: No, it won't `RAND()` without a parameter will be evaluated once for the entire query.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Aha, that is a reason for stable results. Thansk

Comment: Ah, i thought i did it the same way as ORDER BY NEWID(), but im wrong, your right on that one.

Comment: @voroninp - kind of - it's effectively the same as applying no order by, so any "stability" you observe isn't *guaranteed* - the server can return the rows in any order it finds to be efficient. What's efficient could change at any time - e.g. due to other queries also running on the server.

Comment: I thought that explicit column references are required in expression for order by. I was mistaken. But then I see no reason for not accepting constant values.

Comment: If you want to random the order you can use: ORDER BY NEWID()

Comment: @voroninp - it would be better if SQL server was more joined up and could evaluate all complex expressions to determine if they are, in fact, just constant across all rows, and give the same error message as your second example. Alas, such is not so - it sees an expression and doesn't identify it as being constant, so it lets the query run.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from <table_name>
order by 100*rand()+60;
```

> I'm curios how SQL Server interprets this order by query?

Look at the execution plan. There's no sort operator. SQL Server doesn't sort that at all. It's wise enough to know that sorting by a constant is a no-op.

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY a constant doesn't make sense. However, if variable or function is used in ORDER BY, SQL Server will calculate as expression instead of column index.

Consider

```
SELECT *
FROM <table_name>
ORDER BY 0 + 1
```

AND

```
DECLARE @C INT = 0;
SELECT *
FROM <table_name>
ORDER BY @C + 1
```